# Undefined Symbols Error - NewsYC iOS App

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to build the [NewsYC iOS app](https://github.com/Xuzz/newsyc). I can get it to work in the simulator, but when I target my iPhone 5 I get an undefined symbols errors. I'm pretty new to XCode and Objective C so I'm not really sure how to resolve this. I've done some reading about this error in terms of other projects and have the libHNKit linked in the build phases. Not really sure what else needs to happen to correct this.

This is the error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/stephenwalker/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newsyc-gidnwqwyaspbjdevgkudlemjssmd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libHNKit.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/stephenwalker/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/newsyc-gidnwqwyaspbjdevgkudlemjssmd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libHNKit.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HNAnonymousSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SessionListController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HNSessionAuthenticator", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HackerNewsLoginController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HNNetworkActivityController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HNAPISearch", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SearchController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HNSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HackerNewsLoginController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HNSessionController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MainTabBarController.o
      objc-class-ref in SessionProfileController.o
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in HackerNewsLoginController.o
      objc-class-ref in SessionListController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HNObjectBodyRenderer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HNSubmission", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CommentListController.o
      objc-class-ref in EntryReplyComposeController.o
      objc-class-ref in SubmissionTextComposeController.o
      objc-class-ref in SubmissionURLComposeController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HNEntryList", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MainTabBarController.o
      objc-class-ref in MoreController.o
      objc-class-ref in ProfileController.o
      objc-class-ref in SessionProfileController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HNEntry", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CommentListController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing `git submodule init; git submodule update` from Terminal, select HNKit.xcocdeproj in the newsyc project's file navigator. Then click "Build Settings", and then you should see "Multiple Values" next to "Build Active Architecture Only". Click that and set it to "NO".

Comment: That was it! thank you very much. I had to update both the project and the targets.

Comment: @StephenM.WalkerII Glad to hear it worked! By the way, you can mark that an answer answered your question by clicking the check mark next to it. Best of luck!